# Blender Viewport suddenly blank

Tags: 3d-view

The viewport of my Blender project recently went completely blank except the cursor. I rendered once and only the HDR is seen. I've checked all the visibility options and everything seems okay.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Here is a link to the project file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f78fxMpFFBaggM_THZPPZF_1a9s1jjPu

Comment: press the HOME key and blender will try and show you everything in the one view. Very handy when you have zoomed in or out too far.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you've moved your viewport really far away from your scene, out of its render distance, so you couldn't even see your objects anymore.

One quick solution is to select any object of your scene (or just press <kbd>A</kbd>), and use the "view selected" function available in the View menun or via <kbd>Numpad .</kbd>. That's it.

Answer (score -2):

Try going to render then click show/hide render view. That might be what your missing :)

Comment: that's not the issue there